# Need powershell script to extract string

Tags: powershell

I need some help extracting only the 82e80bf1-f9e8-4cdf-82ad-fc63041c0ecf part of the string below.

```
REQUEST_ID=     [java] {"requestId": "82e80bf1-f9e8-4cdf-82ad-fc63041c0ecf"}      [java]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Did you try to search for it? Something like this has been asked thousand times. Even here in SO.  ;-)  Search for Regular Expressions or regex.

Comment: `$string.Split('"')[3]` works, but that's only going to work if you know the line format will be exactly that arrangement of double quotes and content. The part in the middle looks like a dictionary structure that might be sensible to parse properly. String processing depends enormously on what else you know about which parts of the string can change and which cannot.

Answer (score -1):

As other's said, we need more info to help you. What are you trying, what isn't working, etc. This might help you get started:

```
$data = @"
REQUEST_ID=     [java] {"requestId": "82e80bf1-f9e8-4cdf-82ad-fc63041c0ecf"}      [java] 
"@
$pattern = "82e80bf1-f9e8-4cdf-82ad-fc63041c0ecf"

[regex]::Matches($data,$pattern).value
```

Comment: I found that this works for me:$REQUEST_ID=[regex]::matches($REQUEST_ID,'(?<=\": ").+?(?=\"})').value

Comment: The value I'm looking for is constantly changing

Comment: Yeah, regex is usually the answer to stuff like this, that's why I thought the sample would help. Glad you got it working.